# The selected file is a system file that cannot be modified

Tags: java, rad, ibm-rad

I started getting the following error in RAD 9.1.1(websphere 8.5) since yesterday. Also this error is coming on only one project in my workspace. I do have about 7-8 projects which are clean- no errors. Any help or input on this is appreciated..

> The project was not built due to "Internal error - the selected file
>   is a system file that cannot be modified. It will be hidden.". Fix the
>   problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may
>   be inconsistent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved, goto Target, compiled classes folder of that project and DELETE copyarea.db and refresh your project. The error is because the RAD copies the read only files `".copyarea.db"` to the classes folders and during cleanup, RAD fails to delete these files.